# Populate a HTML ListBox with data from a PHP Function

Tags: php, html, listbox

I'm trying to find out how i can populate a HTML ListBox with data i receive in PHP code.

The HTML code:

```
<select id="listObject" name="listObject" size="number_of_options" multiple="multiple" style="width:90%; height:300px">
    <option value="option1">1</option>
    <option value="option2">2</option>
    <option value="Option3">3</option>
</select>
```

And my PHP code:

```
<?php 

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'GET') {
   ( isset($_GET['url'])      ? $url=$_GET['url']            : "");
   ( isset($_GET['channel'])  ? $chan =$_GET['channel']      : "");  
   ( isset($_GET['getdata'])  ? $repeater =$_GET['getdata']  : "");
   ( isset($_GET['putdata'])  ? $ownerUUID =$_GET['putdata']  : "");
   $objectname = "";
   $objectuuid = "";
    
   if(  isset($_GET['url']) ) {
      $entry_line = "** $url | $chan |"; // save the url with a double asterisk marker
      $fp         = fopen("uuid.txt", "w");  // w,r,a
      fputs($fp, $entry_line);
      fclose($fp);
   };
 
  
  if( isset($_GET['putdata']) ) {
    $items = explode(" ", $ownerUUID);
    $objectname = $items[0];
    $objectuuid = $items[1];
    echo "TMOReport|{$objectname}|some more text";
    // tried this but nothing //
    echo '<select name="listObject" id="listObject">';
    echo "<option value={$objectname}></option>";
        echo '</select>';
  };
 ?>
```

I commented the echo part i tried based on something i found but that doesn't seem to work.

The PHP code is being fired by an event on another server with the information and looking to add $objectname to the value of the HTML

Comment: Are you getting any output from your code?

Comment: Yes the $objectname and $objectuuid are being reported back to the calling server in the echo "TMOReport" part so i just need to push them to the HTML ListBox somehow?

Comment: Is the file with the html also a .php file? Also I see in your php code, you are missing an extra `}` at the end. That could be breaking your code.

Comment: Yes the main file is .php with HTML code. That was a copy of the important bit as the other bits weren't relavant. the PHP code works fine

Comment: Please explain what exactly _"The PHP code is being fired by an event on another server"_ means.

Comment: It's being called by an online game and parsing information that i can see coming back. Now i just need to put that information into the HTML ListBox to show on screen in the webbrowser

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the following way, by means of a function which will return the html. This as long as you want to do it as you mention that it is with php.

```
public function populate_listbox($function, $id, $name, $selected = null)
{
    $data = $this->$function();
    $html = '<select id="' . $id . '" name="' . $name . '">';
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        $html .= '<option value="' . $key . '" ' . (($key == $selected) ? 'selected' : '') . '>' . $value . '</option>';
    }
    $html .= '</select>';
    return $html;
}
```

This function receives 3 mandatory parameters and an optional one. `$function` is an array of options, `$id` and `$name` as the name of the variables says it, are the id and the name that will have the Select and finally `$selected` that serves for when you want that one of the options of that select is selected by default.

Comment: Thanks for that. Where would this function be called from and how would this put the value of my $objectname and $objectuuid over into the HTML ListBox id="listObject"?